# Error while adding accompanist-navigation-animation library

Tags: android, kotlin

An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.4.0-rc01' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.0.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

```
//added dependencies
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended"
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0"
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.31.6-rc"
```